# how to return value from key/value dict using SQL from a table that stores keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a table where I store ids of some resources. I want to make sql return values for a keyvalue dictionary without post processing and without a JOIN.

This would be possible using a JOIN. Is there other way to do it, as I only have a few elements in the key/value array.

Programming language is not important. I'm only looking for the SQL that would be able to do it. Postgresql or Mysql.

For the table:

```
|objectId|attribute1|attribute2|
|45      | x        | y        |
|67      | x1       | y2       |
...
```

and I have a dict (object/dict/key value array):

```
{ 45: "My title", 67: "Other title" }
```

And sql result should contain titles instead of values for objectId.

```
select objectId, attribute1 
from table
```

would return:

```
My title | x
Other title | x1
```

Comment: A dictionary is not part of standard sql so a little more explaining is needed here

Comment: Which programming language are you using (where you have that "dictionary")

Comment: Are you really looking for a single solution for Postgres **AND** MySQL? Please add only a tag for the DBMS product you are really using.

Comment: Yes. I have postgresql on test env and mysql on prod env. Programming language is not necessary here.

Comment: Then what is a dictionary?

Comment: okay...  having a different dbms on DEV versus PROD sounds like looking for troubles though...

Comment: As far as I understand you have a 1-1 relation. Why don't you store the titles in the table: `|objectId|title|attribute1|attribute2|`?

Comment: Yes, sometimes you can't afford a licence on all 3-4 environments... There is Oracle on client production env.

Comment: @ThomasSablik there's a reason for 1-1 tables and we want to benefit from it.

Comment: @AlexandruRada OP wants to avoid a JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a `case` expression?

```
select (case when objectId = 45 then 'My title'
             when objectId = 67 then 'Other title'
        end),
       attribute1
from t;
```